# How to save Xdocument without root nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have soap serialized xml file in append mode to file which will result in multiple root nodes like this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:Image id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">
<Name id="ref-4">Component</Name>
<ImmediateState xsi:type="a2:ModifiedState" xmlns:a2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.Plugins/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">Current</ImmediateState>
</a1:Image>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:Image id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">
<Name id="ref-4">Connect</Name>
<ImmediateState xsi:type="a2:ModifiedState" xmlns:a2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.Plugins/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">Current</ImmediateState>
</a1:Image>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have did like this to load XDocument

```
 StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(filename);
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<rootnode>" + Sr.ReadToEnd() + "</rootnode>");
```

Then I did some modification to doc finally I want it save without root nodes and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

When I do

```
doc.Save(filename);
```

I want to save it without root nodes because again I can deserialize the file

So please provide me any alternative way to achieve....

thanks in advance

Comment: First off - an XML string with multiple root nodes is **invalid**. Secondly: your XML *has* a single root node - `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>` - so what is your problem, really? Does your call to `doc.Save()` fail? If so: **what** exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: Ya i know xml is invalid without root nodes but when soap serialize multiple objects i will have multiple <SOAP-ENV:Envelope> root nodes
see my file has two <SOAP-ENV:Envelope> root nodes
and My doc.Save(); will not fail but i want it to to save without root nodes such that i can able desirialize them again any alternative way to save modified xdocumnet doc  without root nodes in a file? please help

Comment: And why is the "artificial" root node a problem when you need to deserialize the XML again??

Comment: soapformatter.desirialize(filestream) will through exception as file will not be in soapforamtter format

Comment: Basically i want my output file to without rootnodes

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the xml without the root nodes.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
doc.Root.Elements().ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.ToString()));
string xmlWithoutRootNodes = sb.ToString();
File.WriteAllText("file", xmlWithoutRootNodes);
```