# how to read xml fragment and validate schema

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

how to parse an xml document and validate the fragment that is not valid using c# ignoring the binary data at the end. is it possible to only parse the xml elements enclosed between the root elements and ignore the binary data.

Comment: [How to get nodes between root nodes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10951514/353147) I did for someone else recently. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `XDocument` validation methods to validate the document as a whole, then as long as you use the override that embeds the validation information in the XDcoument, you can go back over specific elements and get their validity.

Sorry I don't have any code to hand for this at the moment...