# How to write all children of a root of XMLDocument to an XML file

Tags: c#

I want to write only root nodes.
I have tried

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ah0145085\Desktop\Merged1.xml", m_XmlDocument.DocumentElement.InnerXML);
```

But in this case I didnot get the formatted xml file

Comment: try , m_XmlDocument.DocumentElement.OuterXml

Comment: By definition, an XML file can only have a single root. Your title implies that you want to write "all children" to an XML file. This would mean multiple root nodes, or in other words, a file that *isn't* XML. Within your question, you say something completely different. "I want to write only root nodes". "root node**s**" won't be found in an XML file. There's only one. There's a different between "root nodes" and "all children of a root". Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, By mistake I have written "I want to write only root nodes"  My problem is I want to write all the child nodes of a root node i.e resultant xml will contain multiple childs without parent node(I know that the resultant file will not be a valid xml bcoz it will not contain any root only child nodes)

Answer (score 0):

1. To write only the root note, you can do by removing the nodes from the XmlDocument, and saving it afterwards:

> ```
> m_XmlDocument.Element("RootNode").Elements().Remove();
> m_XmlDocument.Save(@"c:\temp\output.xml");
> ```

2. To write only the children nodes, you can do it by removing the root node from the Xml and append it to a string. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947750/how-to-save-xdocument-without-root-nodes), and you do it like this:

> ```
> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
> doc.Root.Elements().ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.ToString()));
> string xmlWithoutRootNodes = sb.ToString();
> File.WriteAllText("file", xmlWithoutRootNodes);
> ```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I want to write only children nodes...So approach 2 is good for me. But in this, we are using XDocument instead of XmlDocument. So can you please provide the code using XmlDocument.

Comment: I think it will be something like this: `doc.Descendants().ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.Value));`

Comment: Using XmlDocument, i have tried,             doc.Descendants().ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.Value));  But I am getting x.Value = null

Comment: Using XmlDocument, i have also tried, doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.Value)); But I am getting x.Value = null

Comment: Using XmlDocument, i have also tried,                                      XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes                                      foreach(XmlNode node in list) { sb.Append(node.value)}         But here I m getting null in node.Value